# issue in dataflow that writes to multiple tables in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, pipeline, dataflow

I use the code from [here](https://partly-cloudy.co.uk/2021/02/05/dataflow-pipeline-to-ingest-into-multiple-bigquery-tables-using-dynamic-destination-and-side-input/)

and change it to:

```
def getFullTableName(pn,tn):
    return "{0}:{1}".format(pn,tn)
...
(
  pipeline | "Read Data From Input Topic" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=data_topic)
           | "Get Table data from input row" >> beam.Map(lambda r : data_ingestion.getData(r))
           | "Write to BigQuery Table" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table = lambda project_name, dest_table_id : getFullTableName(project_name,dest_table_id),                                                                            schema = lambda table, schema_coll : schema_coll[table],                                                                            schema_side_inputs=(schema_coll,),                                                                             create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',                                                                           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        )
```

when running this I get error :

> Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent
> call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1198, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 718, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 843, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py",
> line 1658, in process schema = self.schema(destination,
> *schema_side_inputs) File "multi_table_stream_dyndest.py", line 62, in  KeyError: 'None:ticketing.test2' During handling of the above
> exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call
> last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py",
> line 267, in _execute response = task() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py",
> line 340, in  lambda:
> self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py",
> line 580, in do_instruction return getattr(self, request_type)( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py",
> line 618, in process_bundle
> bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py",
> line 995, in process_bundle
> input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py",
> line 221, in process_encoded self.output(decoded_value) File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 346, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 348, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 707, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 708, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1200, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1281, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1198, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 718, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 843, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py",
> line 1658, in process schema = self.schema(destination,
> *schema_side_inputs) File "multi_table_stream_dyndest.py", line 62, in  KeyError: "**None**:ticketing.test2 [while running 'Write to
> BigQuery
> Table/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-671']"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a table name that is wrong as you can see here:

> KeyError: "None:ticketing.test2

It means, the variable `project_name` is empty (`None`). You have to set it before hand, or get it from the data you as sending. As in the example you are following, the data has the `tablename` field:

`{"tablename" :  "data-analytics-bk:da_belgium_dataset.cust_data", ...`

Answer (score 0):

i add function:
def getFullTableName(self):
logging.info('>>> tablename= %s', "{0}:{1}".format(parseInputData.project,parseInputData.tablename))
return "{0}:{1}".format(parseInputData.project,parseInputData.tablename)

and change the WriteToBigquery:
...
table = lambda l : data_ingestion.getFullTableName()

this fix the problem